# Using same ID does various RETS Server fetch different number of datas?

Tags: rets

I am Using VieleRETS as client applications to fetch data into our MYSQL database. Is there any chances if I use other RETS Client application service such and Rets Connecter to fetch data and same amount of data will be updated of it will vary?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking.

If you are asking whether 2 different MLS Systems have the same schema, the answer is no. Well, not likely at least.

If you are asking whether 2 clients, viele and some other client, will see the same schema from the same MLS system the answer is yes. And in this scenario you should see the same record counts, assuming no defect in the data.

A simple example of data defect would be the DMQL queries ListingID=0+ and ModificationTimestamp=1900-01-01T00:00:00+ should return all listings in both cases. If a listing timestamp or id were null the counts would be off.

Comment: Thanks Bob that problem has been solved.  Here is Another problem   We are facing. We are using Vielerets Service to download RETS data in our database it was working perfectly but now there is an issue .When I download datas it says “This service is temporarily not available ” .